# Redirect to a URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My .htaccess file currently looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/$ ?page=$1 [L]
```

It makes URLs friendly from something like `domain.com/?page=2` to `domain.com/page/2/`.

However, is there a way that I can edit this .htaccess file to make it redirect URLs containing `?page=2` (or any page number) to it's nicely formatted URL (`/page/2/`) automatically? My current one just allows the friendly URL version to "exist", but in no way enforces a redirect to it.

Also, is there a way I can redirect `?page=1` or `/page/1/` just to the main directory/home?

**EDIT:**

After using what I received as an answer from Jon Lin, I was able to solve the second part of my question. Considering that `?page=1` automatically redirected to `/page/1/`, all I had to do was redirect `/page/1/` to the homepage:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+DIRECTORY/(?:page|)/1/?
RewriteRule ^ /DIRECTORY/? [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this right below the `RewriteEngine on` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(?:index\.php|)\?page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1/? [L,R]
```

Comment: @user3681788 I left out a `?` at the end but it works fine for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WmdlO.png

Comment: Hmm, I think it may not be working for me because this file is not located in the root. It is located in a directory. How would I adjust it for that case? `http://domain.com/DIRECTORY/?page=2` -> `http://domain.com/DIRECTORY/page/2/`

Comment: @user3681788 why didn't you put that in your question? You'll need to add "DIRECTORY" everywhere or else it won't work (after the `/+` and before the `/page/`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much! Would you perhaps have an answer for the second part of my question as well? "Also, is there a way I can redirect `?page=1` or `/page/1/` just to the main directory/home?"